# Metal carbonate + carbonic acid?

Tags: acid-base

As metal carbonates are basic would there be a reaction if a sample of, say potassium carbonate, was added to carbonic acid? If so what would be the products? A balanced equation would be useful.
Will this apply to other basic substances if they are added to an acid from which they already have an ion of?

Comment: There would be hydrocarbonates, and in case of other acids, their corresponding [acidic salts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_salt).

Comment: In water  all carbonate will appear as the hydrocarbonate ion. The law of mass action applies as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ce{Na2CO3 + H2CO3 -> 2NaHCO3}$, yielding sodium "bicarbonate", as an example, and in similar fashion, $\ce{Na2SO4 + H2SO4 -> 2NaHSO4}$, or [sodium "bisulfate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bisulfate). The "bi" in this nomenclature meant *two different anions*, and is confusing, as it is the opposite of "bi" in mercury bichloride, two of the same cations. For that reason, *sodium hydrogen sulfate* or *sodium acid sulfate* might be preferred.

Comment: Would it be mercury dichloride?

Comment: Yes, but the "traditional" name was *bichloride*. See many detective stories for its use (https://marymiley.wordpress.com/2009/08/15/popular-poisons-part-ii-mercury-bichloride/).

Comment: The "bi" in bicarbonate question was also in a previous question here http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31083 I wouldn't agree with the statement "The 'bi' in this nomenclature meant two different anions" since it is an obtuse explanation.